# REST API design for specifying value options

Tags: rest, api-design

Given a resource like:

```
GET: /api/examples/1
{
  "id": 1,
  "direction": "North"
}
```

Which also supports `POST, PUT`, how should the possible values for `"direction"` be specified?

Additionally, is there a solution which allows the consumer to know which values will be available if those values are contextual? e.g. if the example is made more complicated:

```
GET: /api/examples/
{[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "startLocation": "Kentucky, USA",
    "direction": "North"
  }
  {
    "id": 2,
    "startLocation": "North Pole",
    "direction": "South"
  }
}]
```

(with something vaguely like):

```
"options": [
  {
    "value": "North",
    "validWhen": "startLocation !== `North Pole`"
  },
  {
    "value": "East",
    "validWhen": "true"
  },
  ...
]
```

Is there a better solution than another resource linked from each `example` which returns the *currently* valid options? If not, how does the consumer know that changing `"startLocation"` changes the valid set of values for `"direction"`?

Comment: Didn't understand your question completely but maybe: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HATEOAS ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you might be looking for is a JSON-Schema. This allows you to strictly describe what options are available in your JSON document, and you can link to the document using a `describedBy` link.

Answer (score 0):

To expand on what @Justas said in his comment, if I understand your requirements correctly, your resource might look something like:

```
GET /examples/1
{
    "startLocation": "Kentucky, USA",
    ...
    "_links": {
        "travel-north": "/some/url",
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think I described the original question very well then. The intent of the "direction" field was to say that it is a property on the resource which has a finite set of valid values (submitting a PUT which assigns `"direction": "squirrel"` would result in a server-side error), and that another property can alter the set of valid values for that field